# Possible Java For Loop Question

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, arraylist

Ok so i'm working on adding a list of about 120 or so specific arrays into an array list
(These are just hypothetical values and names, but the same concept

`private ArrayList<int[]> listofNames = new ArrayList<int[]>();`

```
private static int[] NAME_0 = {x, x, x};
```

`private static int[] NAME_1 = {x, x, x};`

`private static int[] NAME_2 = {x, x, x};`

`private static int[] NAME_3 = {x, x, x};`

Is there a way I can use a for loop to get through NAME_0 to say NAME_120?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use reflection, **but you almost certainly shouldn't**.

Instead of using variables with numbers at the end you should generally use an array of arrays instead. This is what arrays are for, after all.

```
private static int[][] NAMES = new int[][]{
    {x, x, x},
    {x, x, x},
    {x, x, x},
    {x, x, x},
    {x, x, x},
    /// etc.
  };
```

If you're just adding these all to an ArrayList you can probably just use an initializer block instead:

```
private ArrayList<int[]> listofNames = new ArrayList<int[]>();

{
  listofNames.add(new int[]{x, x, x});
  listofNames.add(new int[]{x, x, x});
  listofNames.add(new int[]{x, x, x});
  /// etc.
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, much simpler than adding to an arrayList

Comment: @Ben Also less troublesome with generics. Arrays and generics don't really like each other that much, so it's best to not mix them.

Answer (score 1):

You could do, as Laurence suggested, using reflection

```
    for(int i=0; i<=120; i++)
    {

        Field f = getClass().getField("NAME_" + i);
        f.setAccessible(true);
        listofNames.add((int[]) f.get(null));
    }
```

Also as suggested by Laurence, there are better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want really do in the way from your question you'll have to use reflection. Something like this:

```
Class cls = getClass();
Field fieldlist[] = cls.getDeclaredFields();        
for (Field f : fieldlist) {
    if (f.getName().startsWith("NAME_")) {
        listofNames.add((int[]) f.get(this));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IRL there is little, use for arrays (or mutable bags of data, that in nature, can not be thread safe). For example you could have a function like:

```
public static <T> ArrayList<T> L(T... items) {
    ArrayList<T> result = new ArrayList<T>(items.length + 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
        result.add(items[i]);
    return result;
}
```

So creating a list, and looping it would look:

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Field>> list = L(//
            L(x, x, x), //
            L(x, x, x), //
            L(x, x, x), //
            L(x, x, x) // etc.
    );

    for (int i = 0; i < list.length || 1 < 120; i++) {

    }

    //or
    int i = 0;
    for (ArrayList<Field> elem: list) {
        if (i++ >= 120) break;
        // do else
    }
```